# VLC command line interface on Windows

Tags: windows-xp, video, command-line, streaming, vlc-media-player

Is there a command-line tool for VLC on Windows XP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I run `vlc -h` in Windows XP:

> Dumped content to vlc-help.txt file.

In that file is:

```
Usage: vlc [options] [stream] ...
You can specify multiple streams on the commandline. They will be enqueued in the playlist.
The first item specified will be played first.

Options-styles:
  --option  A global option that is set for the duration of the program.
   -option  A single letter version of a global --option.
   :option  An option that only applies to the stream directly before it
            and that overrides previous settings.

Stream MRL syntax:
  [[access][/demux]://]URL[@[title][:chapter][-[title][:chapter]]] [:option=value ...]

  Many of the global --options can also be used as MRL specific :options.
  Multiple :option=value pairs can be specified.

URL syntax:
  [file://]filename              Plain media file
  http://ip:port/file            HTTP URL
  ftp://ip:port/file             FTP URL
  mms://ip:port/file             MMS URL
  screen://                      Screen capture
  [dvd://][device][@raw_device]  DVD device
  [vcd://][device]               VCD device
  [cdda://][device]              Audio CD device
  udp://[[<source address>]@[<bind address>][:<bind port>]]
                                 UDP stream sent by a streaming server
  vlc://pause:<seconds>          Special item to pause the playlist for a certain time
  vlc://quit                     Special item to quit VLC

 Audio
      --audio, --no-audio        Enable audio (default enabled)
      --volume=<integer [0 .. 1024]>
                                 Default audio volume
      --spdif, --no-spdif        Use S/PDIF when available (default disabled)
      --force-dolby-surround={0 (Auto), 1 (On), 2 (Off)}
                                 Force detection of Dolby Surround
      --audio-replay-gain-mode={none,track,album}
                                 Replay gain mode
      --audio-replay-gain-preamp=<float>
                                 Replay preamp
      --audio-replay-gain-default=<float>
                                 Default replay gain
      --audio-filter=<string>    Audio filters
      --audio-visual=<string>    Audio visualizations 

 Video
  -f, --fullscreen, --no-fullscreen
                                 Fullscreen video output (default disabled)
      --overlay, --no-overlay    Overlay video output (default enabled)
      --video-on-top, --no-video-on-top
                                 Always on top (default disabled)
      --video-title-show, --no-video-title-show
                                 Show media title on video (default enabled)
      --video-title-timeout=<integer>
                                 Show video title for x miliseconds
      --video-title-position={0 (Center), 1 (Left), 2 (Right), 4 (Top), 8 (Bottom), 5 (Top-Left), 6 (Top-Right), 9 (Bottom-Left), 10 (Bottom-Right)}
                                 Position of video title
      --mouse-hide-timeout=<integer>
                                 Hide cursor and fullscreen controller after x
                                 miliseconds
   Snapshot:
      --snapshot-path=<string>   Video snapshot directory (or filename)
      --snapshot-prefix=<string> Video snapshot file prefix
      --snapshot-format={png,jpg}
                                 Video snapshot format
      --snapshot-preview, --no-snapshot-preview
                                 Display video snapshot preview (default
                                 enabled)
      --snapshot-sequential, --no-snapshot-sequential
                                 Use sequential numbers instead of timestamps
                                 (default disabled)
   Window properties:
      --crop=<string>            Video cropping
      --custom-crop-ratios=<string>
                                 Custom crop ratios list
      --aspect-ratio=<string>    Source aspect ratio
      --custom-aspect-ratios=<string>
                                 Custom aspect ratios list
      --video-filter=<string>    Video filter module
      --vout-filter=<string>     Video output filter module

 Subpictures
   On Screen Display:
      --osd, --no-osd            On Screen Display (default enabled)
   Subtitles:
      --sub-file=<string>        Use subtitle file
      --sub-autodetect-file, --no-sub-autodetect-file
                                 Autodetect subtitle files (default enabled)
   Overlays:
      --sub-filter=<string>      Subpictures filter module
   Track settings:
      --audio-language=<string>  Audio language
      --sub-language=<string>    Subtitle language
   Playback control:
      --input-repeat=<integer>   Input repetitions
   Default devices:
      --dvd=<string>             DVD device
      --vcd=<string>             VCD device
      --cd-audio=<string>        Audio CD device
   Network settings:
      --server-port=<integer>    UDP port
  -6, --ipv6, --no-ipv6          Force IPv6 (default disabled)
  -4, --ipv4, --no-ipv4          Force IPv4 (default disabled)

 Input
   Advanced:
      --access-filter=<string>   Access filter module
      --prefer-system-codecs, --no-prefer-system-codecs
                                 Prefer system plugins over VLC (default
                                 disabled)
   Performance options:
      --high-priority, --no-high-priority
                                 Increase the priority of the process (default
                                 disabled)

 Playlist
  -Z, --random, --no-random      Play files randomly forever (default disabled)
  -L, --loop, --no-loop          Repeat all (default disabled)
  -R, --repeat, --no-repeat      Repeat current item (default disabled)
      --play-and-exit, --no-play-and-exit
                                 Play and exit (default disabled)
      --play-and-stop, --no-play-and-stop
                                 Play and stop (default disabled)
      --media-library, --no-media-library
                                 Use media library (default enabled)
      --playlist-tree, --no-playlist-tree
                                 Display playlist tree (default disabled)
      --open=<string>            Default stream
      --auto-preparse, --no-auto-preparse
                                 Automatically preparse files (default enabled)
      --album-art={0 (Manual download only), 1 (When track starts playing), 2 (As soon as track is added)}
                                 Album art policy
  -S, --services-discovery=<string>
                                 Services discovery modules
  -v, --verbose=<integer>        Verbosity (0,1,2)
      --language={auto,en,ar,pt_BR,en_GB,bg,ca,zh_TW,cs,da,nl,fi,fr,gl,ka,de,he,hu,it,ja,ko,ms,oc,fa,pl,pt_PT,pa,ro,ru,zh_CN,sr,sk,sl,es,sv,tr,uk}
                                 Language
      --advanced, --no-advanced  Show advanced options (default disabled)
      --interact, --no-interact  Interface interaction (default enabled)
      --show-intf, --no-show-intf
                                 Show interface with mouse (default disabled)
  -I, --intf=<string>            Interface module
      --extraintf=<string>       Extra interface modules
      --control=<string>         Control interfaces

 Hot keys
      --key-toggle-fullscreen=<integer>
                                 Fullscreen
      --key-leave-fullscreen=<integer>
                                 Leave fullscreen
      --key-play-pause=<integer> Play/Pause
      --key-faster=<integer>     Faster
      --key-slower=<integer>     Slower
      --key-next=<integer>       Next
      --key-prev=<integer>       Previous
      --key-stop=<integer>       Stop
      --key-jump-extrashort=<integer>
                                 Very short backwards jump
      --key-jump+extrashort=<integer>
                                 Very short forward jump
      --key-jump-short=<integer> Short backwards jump
      --key-jump+short=<integer> Short forward jump
      --key-jump-medium=<integer>
                                 Medium backwards jump
      --key-jump+medium=<integer>
                                 Medium forward jump
      --key-jump-long=<integer>  Long backwards jump
      --key-jump+long=<integer>  Long forward jump
      --key-quit=<integer>       Quit
      --key-vol-up=<integer>     Volume up
      --key-vol-down=<integer>   Volume down
      --key-vol-mute=<integer>   Mute
      --key-audio-track=<integer>
                                 Cycle audio track
      --key-audiodevice-cycle=<integer>
                                 Cycle through audio devices
      --key-subtitle-track=<integer>
                                 Cycle subtitle track
      --key-aspect-ratio=<integer>
                                 Cycle source aspect ratio
      --key-crop=<integer>       Cycle video crop
      --key-deinterlace=<integer>
                                 Cycle deinterlace modes
      --key-wallpaper=<integer>  Toggle wallpaper mode in video output
      --key-random=<integer>     Random
      --key-loop=<integer>       Normal/Repeat/Loop
   Zoom:
      --key-zoom-quarter=<integer>
                                 1:4 Quarter
      --key-zoom-half=<integer>  1:2 Half
      --key-zoom-original=<integer>
                                 1:1 Original
      --key-zoom-double=<integer>
                                 2:1 Double
   Jump sizes:
      --extrashort-jump-size=<integer>
                                 Very short jump length
      --short-jump-size=<integer>
                                 Short jump length
      --medium-jump-size=<integer>
                                 Medium jump length
      --long-jump-size=<integer> Long jump length
      --bookmark1=<string>       Playlist bookmark 1
      --bookmark2=<string>       Playlist bookmark 2
      --bookmark3=<string>       Playlist bookmark 3
      --bookmark4=<string>       Playlist bookmark 4
      --bookmark5=<string>       Playlist bookmark 5
      --bookmark6=<string>       Playlist bookmark 6
      --bookmark7=<string>       Playlist bookmark 7
      --bookmark8=<string>       Playlist bookmark 8
      --bookmark9=<string>       Playlist bookmark 9
      --bookmark10=<string>      Playlist bookmark 10
  -h, --help, --no-help          print help for VLC (can be combined with
                                 --advanced and --help-verbose) (default
                                 enabled)
  -H, --full-help, --no-full-help
                                 Exhaustive help for VLC and its modules
                                 (default disabled)
      --longhelp, --no-longhelp  print help for VLC and all its modules (can
                                 be combined with --advanced and
                                 --help-verbose) (default disabled)
      --help-verbose, --no-help-verbose
                                 ask for extra verbosity when displaying help
                                 (default disabled)
  -l, --list, --no-list          print a list of available modules (default
                                 disabled)
  -l, --list-verbose, --no-list-verbose
                                 print a list of available modules with extra
                                 detail (default disabled)
  -p, --module=<string>          print help on a specific module (can be
                                 combined with --advanced and --help-verbose)
      --ignore-config, --no-ignore-config
                                 no configuration option will be loaded nor
                                 saved to config file (default disabled)
      --save-config, --no-save-config
                                 save the current command line options in the
                                 config (default disabled)
      --reset-config, --no-reset-config
                                 reset the current config to the default
                                 values (default disabled)
      --reset-plugins-cache, --no-reset-plugins-cache
                                 resets the current plugins cache (default
                                 disabled)
      --version, --no-version    print version information (default disabled)
      --config=<string>          use alternate config file
      --version, --no-version    print version information (default disabled)

 Note: add --advanced to your command line to see advanced options.

To get exhaustive help, use '-H'.
```

[Addendum by @gman]  A few notable things:

1. To get an even longer list use `-H` (instead of `-h`). It's the last thing in the short help.
2. To get a list of modules

   ```
   vlc --list
   ```
3. To get options for a specific module

   ```
   vlc --advanced -p <modulename>
   ```
4. Some options require you to turn on filters or turn off other features.

   For example:

   - To turn the video over

     ```
     vlc --video-filter transform --transform-type 180 filename
     ```
   - To crop video

     ```
     vlc --video-filter croppadd --croppadd-cropleft=215 --croppadd-cropright=215 --croppadd-croptop 100 --croppadd-cropbottom 100 filename
     ```
   - To zoom video

     ```
     vlc --no-autoscale --zoom 8  filename
     ```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean *command-line interface* or *starting VLC from shell with parameters*? If latter, you can always run VLC with arguments you want, no matter what OS it works on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have VLC installed somewhere in your computer or if you have the portable version, then you can use the full path of vlc.exe or add it to PATH and then execute its command line options as said in the best answer. In Linux, you can just execute `vlc args`.